# Comparing String in two columns for differences

Tags: excel

I’m attempting to compare two columns of strings for differences.

[image: actual data]

I have these two lists of states that I need to extract the differences. I need to see if Column F is missing anything from Column G. Is there a way to formulate this without running a macro?  Thanks all!

Comment: Posting actual sample data in markdown format helps a lot, pictures are just terrible to work from.

Comment: Here is a [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for you to create a markdown table that you can copy and paste to your post so other contributors can easily copy your sample data and work on it. You can import a csv or directly copy and past your data to the tool to generate the markdown table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using **Power Query**. 
Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Use **From Table** function to add your source table to the power query editor, **Remove** all irrelevant columns and leave `Column F` and `Column G` only. Below is a small example I am using;

[image: Sample Table]

2. Right click the header of `Column G` to make a **Duplicate Column** of Column G;

[image: Duplication]

3. Use **Split Column** function under `Transform` tab to split Column G by comma `,` and make sure set the outputs to be put into **Rows**:

[image: Split Column]

4. **Add a custom column** under `Add Column` tab with this formula: `=Text.PositionOf([Col_F],[Col_G])>=0` then you should have something like below:

[image: Custom Column]

5. Click the filter button on the right hand side of the column header to **Filter** the `Custom column` to show `FALSE` results only;
6. Use **Merge Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to merge `Column F` and `Column G - Copy` with semicolon `;` as the delimiter. Then you should have:

[image: Merged]

7. Use **Group By** Function to group `Column G` by the merged column with the following set-up. Once done you will notice the `Sum` column is showing errors which is expected.

[image: Group By]

8. Go to the formula bar and **replace the formula** with this one:`= Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"Merged"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Col_G],","), type text}})`, then you should have something like the following:

[image: Text Combine]

9. Then you can **split** the merged column by semicolon `;` to retrieve the original `Column F` and `Column G`;

[image: Splited]

10. **Rename** each column as desired and then **Close & Load** the output to a new worksheet (by default). Then you should have something like the following:

[image: Outcome]

> The above steps can be simplified if you do not need to show `Column G` in the output table. You can skip Step 2, 6 and 9. The tricky bit is Step 8 where you are not creating a new step but rather change the formula used in the previous step. The key is to replace the original `List.Sum` function with `Text.Combine` function in the formula to get the desired output.

Here are the Power Query **M Codes** behind the scene:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col_F", type text}, {"Col_G", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Col_G", "Col_G - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Col_G", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Col_G"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Col_G", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each Text.PositionOf([Col_F],[Col_G])>=0),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = false)),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Col_F", "Col_G - Copy"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"Merged"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Col_G],","), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Merged.1", "Merged.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Merged.1", type text}, {"Merged.2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Merged.1", "Col_F"}, {"Merged.2", "Col_G"}, {"Sum", "Col_Missing"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @Terry W but my enterprise won’t let me install Power Query :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `VLOOKUP` function to determine which strings are missing from the other set.

Assuming your data starts in row 2, write the following:

`=VLOOKUP(G2, [ highlight all the data in column F and lock it], 1, 0)`

Any `#N/A` that appears means that data is not in the other data set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to see specificly which data is missing you can use this formula:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),1,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),1,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),4,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),4,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),7,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),7,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),10,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),10,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),13,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),13,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(TRIM(F1),16,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(TRIM(F1),16,2))&","&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(F1,19,2),TRIM(G1),1)),"",MID(F1,19,2))

Comment: Thanks @Roger H. This works well when comparing what F has that G but I can’t quite get that to flip to find what G has that F doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

One bit that I recently have tried is:

```
=IF(B2=“TX”,REPLACE(F2,SEARCH(“CO,”,F2)3,””))
```

This finds “CO,” in my string in F2 and pulls it out leaving me with “AR,FL,KY,LA,NJ,NM,OK,TX,”

May not be the most elegant way, but . . . How can I extend this to also pull out “TX,” “AR,” “LA,” etc (the remaining string from G2) from F2 as well?

I’m looking to see if anything from G2 is missing from F2. So my net result should be a blank cell in this case.